# How to parse a Clickhouse-SQL statement using ANTRL4?

Tags: java, sql, antlr4, clickhouse

**Objective :** Add an additional `WHERE` clause to any given Clickhouse statement.

I'm using the following Antlr grammars to generate Java classes for a lexer & parser.

Lexer grammar

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/utils/antlr/ClickHouseLexer.g4

Parser grammar

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/utils/antlr/ClickHouseParser.g4

**Problem :** I cannot figure out/understand how to interact or create the appropriate POJOs for use with the generated classes that Antlr produces.

Example of statement

```
String query = "INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'Hello, world'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'def')"
```

Goal of SQL (enrichment code)

```
String enrichedQuery = SqlParser.enrich(query);
System.out.println(enrichedQuery);

//Output
>> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'Hello, world'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'def') (WHERE X IN USERS)
```

I have the follow Java main

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        String query = "INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'Hello, world'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'def')"
        ClickhouseLexer = new ClickhouseLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(query));
        
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ClickHouseParser = new ClickHouseParser (tokens);          
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    }
}
```

Comment: First, write a driver that just parses the input string. Replace "HelloParser" with "ClickHouseParser", "HelloLexer" with "ClickHouseLexer" in the above main(). Test that, then you can worry about modifying the parser tree for your goal.

Comment: @kaby76 Appreciate the message. Please see the revised code. I erroneously hand-jammed a quick synopsis of what I was trying to achieve. That has since been updated prior to your message

Comment: Try `var str = CharStreams.fromString(input); var lexer = new ClickHouseLexer(str); var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); var parser = new ClickHouseParser(tokens); var tree = parser.queryStmt();`. But the parser grammar is targeted for C, not Java. So, you have to change the parser grammar: add `@header { import java.util.Set; }` after `options {...}` at the top; `std::set<std::string> attrs` changed to `Set<String> attrs`; `attrs.count(` changed to `attrs.contains(`; `attrs.insert(` changed to `attrs.add(`. Similar for `clauses`.

Comment: @kaby76 I appreciate the response and again thanks for following up with this. Been changing those out those C++ parts as I was awaiting further input from the Stackoverflow community. After that the aforementioned is corrected, any guidance on how I could grab appropriate nodes to start injecting additional where clauses (after the AST is built)

Comment: There are several ways you could implement the `where` clauses, but an easy solution is to just write a tree walker (likely you can use the generated Antlr listener for the grammar) that outputs at each leaf the original code, but when you get to a particular node that the `where` occurs, output that.

Comment: Because of subqueries it's not clear which `where` clause you wanna add. Is it for the top level select only? And is this only for select statements or the other statements too that can have a where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at [TokenStreamRewriter](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.html).

First, let's get the grammars ready.

1 - with `TokenStreamRewriter` we'll want to preserve whitespace, so let's change the `-> skip` directives to `->channel(HIDDEN)`

At the end of the Lexer grammar:

```
// Comments and whitespace

MULTI_LINE_COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);
SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT: '--' ~('\n'|'\r')* ('\n' | '\r' | EOF) -> channel(HIDDEN);
WHITESPACE: [ \u000B\u000C\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);  // '\n' can be part of multiline single query
```

2 - The C++ specific stuff just guards against using keywords more than once.  You don't really need that check for your purposes (and it could be done in a post-parse Listener if you DID need it).  So let's just lose the language specific stuff:

```
engineClause: engineExpr (
    orderByClause
    | partitionByClause
    | primaryKeyClause
    | sampleByClause
    | ttlClause
    | settingsClause
)*
;
```

and

```
dictionaryAttrDfnt
    : identifier columnTypeExpr (
        DEFAULT literal
        | EXPRESSION columnExpr
        | HIERARCHICAL
        | INJECTIVE
        | IS_OBJECT_ID
    )*
    ;
dictionaryEngineClause
    : dictionaryPrimaryKeyClause? (
        sourceClause
        | lifetimeClause
        | layoutClause
        | rangeClause
        | dictionarySettingsClause
    )*
    ;
```

NOTE:  There seems to be an issue with the grammar not accepting the actual values for an insert statement:

```
insertStmt
    : INSERT INTO TABLE? (
        tableIdentifier
        | FUNCTION tableFunctionExpr
    ) columnsClause? dataClause
    ;

columnsClause
    : LPAREN nestedIdentifier (COMMA nestedIdentifier)* RPAREN
    ;
dataClause
    : FORMAT identifier              # DataClauseFormat
    | VALUES                         # DataClauseValues // <- problem on this line
    | selectUnionStmt SEMICOLON? EOF # DataClauseSelect
    ;
```

(I'm not going to try to fix that part, so I've commented your input to accommodate)

(It would also help if the top level rule needed with an `EOF` token; without that ANTLR just stops parsing after `VALUE`.  An EOF at the end of a root rule is considered a best practice for exactly this reason.)

The Main program:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStreamRewriter;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class TSWDemo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new TSWDemo().run(CharStreams.fromString("INSERT INTO t VALUES /* (1, 'Hello, world'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'def') */"));
    }

    public void run(CharStream charStream) {
        var lexer = new ClickHouseLexer(charStream);
        var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new ClickHouseParser(tokenStream);
        var tsw = new TokenStreamRewriter(tokenStream);
        var listener = new TSWDemoListener(tsw);

        var queryStmt = parser.queryStmt();
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, queryStmt);

        System.out.println(tsw.getText());
    }
}
```

The Listener:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStreamRewriter;

public class TSWDemoListener extends ClickHouseParserBaseListener {
    private TokenStreamRewriter tsw;

    public TSWDemoListener(TokenStreamRewriter tsw) {
        this.tsw = tsw;
    }
    @Override
    public void exitInsertStmt(ClickHouseParser.InsertStmtContext ctx) {
        tsw.insertAfter(ctx.getStop(), " (WHERE X IN USERS)");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (WHERE X IN USERS) /* (1, 'Hello, world'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'def') */
```

Comment: This was most helpful, Mike. Thanks for the thorough explanation